# Understanding Analyse > Slope function of QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope

Playing around with QGIS I discovered the tool 'Analyse > Slope' and I wondered what it actually tells me.

Is it an additional information to let's say contourlines, which already provide info on the slope to be expected?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DEM (Digital Elevation model, raster data), based on the value of each pixel, it will calculate the slope, thus how steep the surface is at each pixel, compared to neighboring pixels.

> Slope is the angle of inclination to the horizontal.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=slope#slope